# Python, SQlite 3 insert super slow

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

for some reason the insert instruction is painfully slow.

By painfully slow, I mean I go from 400 updates a second to about 5.

This is the method in question:

```
@app.route('/sendData/<path:data>', methods=['POST'])
def receiveData(data): #Data = '0,2C7,2C6,1C8,2C2,1' always.
    def h(point):
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO points (x, y) VALUES({},{});".format(*point.split(",")))
        g.db.commit()

    cur = g.db.cursor()
    #list(map(h, data.split("C"))) This enables the slow.
    return "Done"
```

When I uncomment that map, it goes painfully slow. I also tried this other method, same thing.

```
def receiveData(data): #Data = '0,2C7,2C6,1C8,2C2,1' always.
    cur = g.db.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO points (x, y) VALUES({}, {});".format(*data.split("C",1)[0].split(",")))
    g.db.commit()
    if data.count("C") == 0:
        return "Done"
    else:
        return receiveData(data.split("C",1)[1])
```

I don't think I need to commit every single insert, but putting it at the end of each function makes no difference.

Comment: accumulate lots and use `executemany`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you collect all your data you want to insert and then build multi-row inserts with (you could test performance wise which limit is best) a 100 or more points inserted at one time.

Unfortunately depending on your version, there is not typical `INSERT ... VALUES(...), VALUES(..), ...` as we know it from most DBMS, but there is a solution in doing this adapted from this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609637/is-it-possible-to-insert-multiple-rows-at-a-time-in-an-sqlite-database)

```
INSERT INTO 'points' (x, y)
      SELECT 0 AS 'x', 2 AS 'y'
UNION SELECT 7, 2
UNION SELECT 6, 1
UNION SELECT 8, 2
UNION SELECT 2, 1
```

Comment: Problem is, I want it as fast as possible and as real time. I might just use a list of points, given enough ram and save it in an sql database if I need. Maybe I'm using sql for the wrong application. Oh yeah, I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: @RustyShackleford then i would switch to in-memory tables (:memory:) they are not tremendously faster, but as your table grows memory access will give better results compared to disk tables - her some one [benchmarked this] before

Comment: and if you really just have points - or always the same model of data with no varchar fields but actually fixed width fields, then you are probably better of just reading the whole table into a python array and traverse this - for sure faster than having python use sqllite for this - i figure you don't need queries and table joins and all that anyhow, so using database should not be your choice!

Comment: I do need queries and use them just as much as I write data to the table. However, the queries don't have any measurable speed penalty. But, there wouldn't be a problem with writing to the table every once in a while once the list gets too big.